# feather edges of view box of scrolling background with opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css

i currently have a scrolling background in one small area of my website and i am trying to have the image fade out as it gets to the sides of the view box. so when the image enters the viewing area it gets opacity and then becomes fully opaque as it comes into the center and then fades out again as it hits the other edge of the view box.  I have tried applying gradients with opacity but had no luck and have also tried placing a box with opacity over the viewing area so that when the image scrolls into the area it would change opacity but neither of these things worked.

i am using one image as the background but adding it into the scroller twice so that it can loop and look like it is never ending

any ideas on how to do this?

for the scrolling background i am using the jquery smooth div scroll plugin

edit:  here is some of the code i tried

my original scrolling elements... self explanatory

```
<div id='cloud-viewer'>
  <div class='scrollWrapper'> //view box
    <div id='cloud-wrapper' class='scrollableArea'> //scrolling in here
      <div id='clouds-1' class='clouds'></div>
      <div id='clouds-2' class='clouds'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i have tried to put an element with opacity in the code a few ways as seen below

```
<div id='cloud-viewer'>
  <div id='opaque'></div> //this had css to keep it in pos and opacity
  <div class='scrollWrapper'>
    <div id='opaque'></div> //this gets scrolled...
    <div id='cloud-wrapper' class='scrollableArea'>
      <div id='clouds-1' class='clouds'></div>
      <div id='clouds-2' class='clouds'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What didn't work about what you already tried? Post your code.

Comment: well, what didn't work is that the opacity was not applied to the image. i will post the code in the question

Comment: It's imperative that you post your non-working code so we can see what the issue is.

Comment: added some code.  i have also tried to apply a gradient with opacity to each of the bounding element, but unfortunately that is applied only to the background, not the elements inside of the box

Answer (score 1):

I would make 2 transparent PNG images that fade (with a gradient) from the background color of your website to transparent. The first one would be for the left side (bg color to transparent) and the second would be a horizontally flipped version of the first (transparent to bg color). Just absolutely position these two images on top of the left/right sides of the scrollable area and allow for the image to slide behind it. If your viewable area is a fixed size, you could also do this with one large image. Make sense?

If you look at this site for example (not mine): http://www.pauljnoble.com/photos, it does what I *think* you're looking for. And here's the overlay image they're using: http://www.pauljnoble.com/img/bg/photos-shadow-3.png.